# My App Keeps Stoping whenever i ran the app in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am currently working on login page and now my app is stoping. My kotlin code is here. This is my practice app and its base language is kotlin. Here Xml code helps me to create a login page and the kotlin code here helps to toast

```
package com.venkat.kotlin

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast


class NewActivity : AppCompatActivity() , View.OnClickListener{

    override fun onClick(pO: View?) {
          Toast.makeText(this@NewActivity,"we clicked on button! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    lateinit var etNumber : EditText
    lateinit var etPs : EditText
    lateinit var btnLogin : Button
    lateinit var txtForgetPassword : TextView
    lateinit var txtRegister : TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new)

        title = "Log in"

        etNumber = findViewById(R.id.etNumber)
        etPs = findViewById(R.id.etPs)
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.txtForgetPassword)
        txtForgetPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtForgetPassword)
        txtRegister =  findViewById(R.id.txtRegister)

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

}
```

After this here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00D84A"
    tools:context=".NewActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avengers_logo" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etNumber"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPs"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtForgetPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:text="@string/forget_password"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

no error is been displayed on here in android studio. In my android studio other apps are running. so this code has problem.

Comment: In log set no filter and check errors, may be there will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give attention to ide warnings.

```
btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.txtForgetPassword)
txtForgetPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtForgetPassword)
```

ide is highlighting `findViewById(R.id.txtForgetPassword)` and saying the warning
`The id R.id.txtForgetPassword has already been looked up in this method; possible cut & paste error? (First usage here)`

You are trying to assign TextView to Button, thus cast cannot happened and exception thrown. Just change as following:

```
btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)
```